# Realtivistic interaction in graphene

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, graphene

Near the Dirac points, Graphene can be described by the Lagrangian equivalent to free massless Weyl spinors:
$$
L_0 = \overline{\Psi}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\Psi
\quad.
$$
From the theoretical point of view, the next logical step is to add to this Lagrangian some relativistically-invariant interactions. One can argue (see [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b2be/f846a9fb226609e47ba4f8bdd5740456146c.pdf) around equation (2.6)) that its simplest form compatible with graphene's symmetries is
$$
L_1 = g_{D2} (\overline{\Psi}\gamma_{35}\Psi)^2+g_{C1}(\overline{\Psi}\Psi)^2
\quad.
$$

Does anybody know if there are physical régimes in which graphene is actually described by such a Lagrangian? Or any other explicitly Lorentz-invariant interaction?